# Exception while trying to read out holding registers from device via Modbus/TCP

Tags: java, client-server, master-slave, modbus, modbus-tcp

im trying to read values from holding registers of a device (PowerMonitor made by Weidmüller) using Modbus/TCP. I use java and a modbus library called "jamod". My code:

```
public class Master1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            TCPMasterConnection con = null; // the connection
            ModbusTCPTransaction trans = null; // the transaction
            ReadMultipleRegistersRequest req = null; // the request
            ReadMultipleRegistersResponse res = null; // the response
            byte[] ip = { (byte) 127, (byte) 0, (byte) 0, (byte) 1 }; // the
                                                                        // powermonitor
                                                                        // actually
                                                                        // has a
                                                                        // different
                                                                        // IP

            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip); // the slave's
                                                                // adress

            int port = 502; // Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;

            int ref = 4; // the reference; offset where to start reading from,
                            // =n-1

            int count = 4; // the number of Reg's to read
            int repeat = 100; // a loop for repeating the transaction

            // 2. Open the connection
            con = new TCPMasterConnection(addr);
            con.setPort(port);
            con.connect();

            // 3. Prepare the request
            req = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(ref, count);

            // 4. Prepare the transaction
            trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
            trans.setRequest(req);

            // 5. Execute the transaction repeat times
            int k = 0;
            do {
                trans.execute();
                res = (ReadMultipleRegistersResponse) trans.getResponse();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Status register " + (ref + i + 1)
                            + ": " + res.getRegisterValue(i));
                }
                k++;
            } while (k < repeat);

            // 6. Close the connection
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

While running this code in eclipse (with the actual IP), im getting this on the console:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:171)  
    at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:193)  
    at Master1.main(Master1.java:44)  
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:171)  
    at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:193)  
    at Master1.main(Master1.java:44)  
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:171)  
    at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:193)  
    at Master1.main(Master1.java:44)  
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)    
    at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransport.readResponse(ModbusTCPTransport.java:171)  
    at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:193)  
    at Master1.main(Master1.java:44)  
net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusIOException: Executing transaction failed (tried 3 times)  
    at net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction.execute(ModbusTCPTransaction.java:197)  
    at Master1.main(Master1.java:44)
```

When im running this program with EasyModbusTCP Server Simulator at localhost (like above), there isnt a problem and im getting the values stored in holding registers.
So what am i doing wrong? I really dont know what to do. I hope the way im asking is ok (im very new here). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find out what was the issue? I am having the exact same exception.

Comment: It's quite a long time ago but I think the solution was to add the code line "req.setUnitID(1);" after the code line "req = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(ref, count);". Does this help you?

Comment: No, I do have `req.setUnitID` already.. I still haven't managed to solve this.

Comment: Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @Ananth were you guys able to solve this ?

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava No, we couldn't. We shifted to Python for this (pymodbus library) and that solved this problem (though we ran into other problems with that).

Comment: @Ananth: Thanks solved this problem , somehow the modbus slave id was not configured properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ReadMultipleRegistersRequest req = new ReadMultipleRegistersRequest(ref, count);
req.setUnitID(ID);  // ID - the slave's adress
```

Comment: Answers that contain only code (and poorly formatted code at that) are generally considered to be poor quality. Can you [edit] your answer and explain how the code in your answer solves the problem? Oh, and by the way, I suggest that you take the [tour] and visit the [help] and learn how to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).